# I want to add a additional html link to the node view ? How can I do it?

Tags: nodes, hooks

I want to add some extra information like an additional html link along with the node data at node render.

Hope I tried googling but came to know that we can do it through `hook_node_view_alter`, but not able to do it.

Comment: Hello. Please be more specific. *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."* - so what link is it? Where is it supposed to link to? Is it supposed to be editable by node's owner? Why can't you just write it in the body?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with any of the following hooks:

- [hook_node_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7)
- [hook_node_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7)
- [hook_entity_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view/7)
- [hook_entity_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_alter/7)

The choice of hook would depend on the requirements and/or personal preference.

Using hook_node_view_alter():

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view_alter().
 */
function example_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  $build['#suffix'] = '<strong>Hello</strong>';
}
```

Using hook_node_view():

```
function nodeapi_example_node_view($node, $build_mode = 'full') {
  if (variable_get('nodeapi_example_node_type_' . $node->type, FALSE)) {
    // Make sure to set a rating, also for nodes saved previously and not yet rated.
    $rating = isset($node->nodeapi_example_rating) ? $node->nodeapi_example_rating : 0;
    $node->content['nodeapi_example'] = array(
      '#markup' => theme('nodeapi_example_rating', array('rating' => $rating)),
        '#weight' => -1,
    );
  }
}
```

*(Snippet from the excellent [examples module](https://drupal.org/project/examples))*

Comment: thanks angheloko..! but could you please let me know how to add the "my additional content" to the $build array returned in node_view_alter